# Unable to use EMGU CV to grab images from RTSP stream continuously

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv, rtsp

I am trying to obtain images from an RTSP Stream from an IP Camera using a C# Windows Forms application. I am using EMGU CV to capture stream continuously but the RTSP Steam stops after a few seconds and then the imageGrabbedEvent never fires.

My purpose is simple: to get every frame from the camera and analyze it.

I am using a HIKVision IP Camera(DS-2CD2683G1-IZ) with an IP Address of 192.168.1.64 streaming RTSP on port 554 (which is the default IP address and port number for many Hikvision IP Cameras)

```
DateTime LastTimeImageGrabReinitialised = new DateTime();


public void InitializeCameraEMGUStream()
        {
            //added a datetime to the URL as recommended by another answer but it didnt help.
            VideoCapture myVideoCapture = new VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:mysecretpassword@192.168.1.64:554/ch1/main/av_stream?"+DateTime.Now.ToString());
            myVideoCapture.ImageGrabbed += imageGrabbedEvent;
            myVideoCapture.Start();

            LastTimeImageGrabReinitialised = DateTime.Now;

        }

private void imageGrabbedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lastTimeImageGrabbed = DateTime.Now;
            try
            {
                Mat m = new Mat();
                myVideoCapture.Retrieve(m);
                LatestAcquiredImage = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Bitmap;
                pictureBox.Image = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Bitmap;
                imgEntrada = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {



            }

            //I tried adding some logic to reinitialize the stream after a few hundred milliseconds, 
            //but it seems the reinitialization takes a while to obtain a clear image and many frames cannot be read.
            if((DateTime.Now- LastTimeImageGrabReinitialised).TotalMilliseconds>200)
            {

                myVideoCapture.Start();
                LastTimeImageGrabReinitialised = DateTime.Now;
            }

        }
```

I have gone through a couple of answers available online but cannot find a definitive way to keep the stream alive. I would really appreciate any help in this regard.

FYI: What I have already tried:

1. I tried reinitializing the VideoCapture every some time but it is slow and many initial frames are noisy/unclear images.
2. I already tried using VLC.Dotnet to run the RTSP steam, the stream works perfectly fine but to grab an image and convert it to and Image is very slow, primarily because of VLCControl.TakeSnapshot() saves the file on disk. At best, this consumes more then 500milliseconds and many frames are lost during that time.
3. I additionally also tried using RTSPClientSharp, while using that, the imageGrabbed event fires regularly but I but was unable to get to display a decoded image.
4. I tried getting images from the camera using HTTP, however, each image takes more than 600ms to arrive and the camera won't accept any other connection requests in the meanwhile, hence many frames are again lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to find a solution.

While Emgu's RTSP stream grabber isnt stable, RTSPClientSharp is a pretty stable implementation for grabbing individual frames from RTSP streams and converting them into Bitmaps which you can use for any image processing in .NET. The sample provided in the GitWorks right out of the box.

https://github.com/BogdanovKirill/RtspClientSharp

After downloading the project from GitHub, you can try out the grabbing using following stream(if it is still online, check using VLC to ensure stream is still available)

rtsp://rtsp.stream/pattern

Comment: Hi, does this support H.265 / H.265+?

Comment: Most of these libraries use ffmpeg as an underlying decoding library that does the real work of converting raw bits and pieces of changing pixels into recognizable picture. I haven't tested but I believe it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with an RTSP stream and I solved it by using `QueryFrame` along with a timeout instead of the `ImageGrabbed` event so that might be worth a try with your camera. This is the main processing loop that grabs the frames, I haven't observed any unexpected dropped frames I've only seen the `QueryFrame` timeout for reasons like the camera having a power loss:

```
try
{
    if (!cameraOpened)
    {
        LogMessage("Opening camera stream...");
        var openTask = Task.Run(() => capture = new Capture("rtsp://admin:redacted@10.0.0.22:554"));
        if (await Task.WhenAny(openTask, Task.Delay(20000)) != openTask)
        {
            LogMessage("Unable to open camera stream");
        }
        else
        {
            LogMessage("Camera stream opened");
            cameraOpened = true;
        }
    }
    if (cameraOpened)
    {
        var captureTask = Task.Run(() => inputFrame = capture.QueryFrame());
        if (await Task.WhenAny(captureTask, Task.Delay(5000)) != captureTask)
        {
            LogMessage("Camera connection lost");
            cameraOpened = false;
        } 
        else
        {
            if (inputFrame != null && !inputFrame.IsEmpty)
            {
                frameQueue.Enqueue(inputFrame);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogMessage(ex.Message);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

`frameQueue` is declared as follows and the processing occurs in a separate thread which might help things as well. I wrote the code quite a while ago, instead of the this I'd now use the `ConcurrentQueue` class.

```
Queue myQ = new Queue();
Queue frameQueue = Queue.Synchronized(myQ);
```

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for the reply. I tried the method above, The QueryFrame method starts returning null inputFrame after  running for around 1 minute. Also it seems the images arrive with a delay and eventually that delay pile up, Before the QueryFrame started returning null, the video is around 30 seconds delayed(based on camera clock)

Comment: That sounds like something not keeping up, one quick thing to try would be using `QuerySmallFrame` instead to get a half-size image and if that works maybe try adjusting the video format in the camera to something smaller or more compressed. You could also try looking at the Visual Studio Profiler to see if there's any bottlenecks in the code you weren't expecting.